# Can I display Controls after a certain event occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, binding

I am trying to extract the data from a database adapting to what user wants.It a text data with multiple lines.Its more like asking questions and when a certain question appears,I want a text box or a true false to be displayed. Since I can't really hard code it on the form and I don't know what order the question is gonna appear in, I just want that whenever the question appears, a text box is displayed under it so user can enter a value.can anybody tell me how to do it?

I am using a Grid View in WPF and binding it to the data source.I will really appreciate any help on this one.

I am using C sharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamictextbox You can add controls at runtime as follows:

Add a Panel Control to where you will be adding the text boxes. Then do something like this:

```
TextBox dynamictextbox = new TextBox();
dynamictextbox.Text = "(Enter some text)";
dynamictextbox.ID = "dynamictextbox";
Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamictextbox);
```

Since you're using the grid View you'll have to do the whole .findControl() thing to find the panel. But this should give you the right idea.

**EDIT #1:**

Maybe using JQuery you could attach yourself to the CELL or something in the cell using something like:

```
$("#question_id").append("<input type='text'>question</input>")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What I am trying to figure out is since I really don't know the page pr place where a particular question is going to be displayed(I am just retrieving rows from the database),it has to be bound to the question somehow.